# URL mangled when redirecting with Backbone

Tags: javascript, redirect, backbone.js

I see a strange behavior when redirecting to a URL with Backbone router.

If I try to redirect to:

```
//myserver/component_issues/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar:sonarqube
```

... everything is fine, but I get a 404 when I try to redirect to:

```
//myserver/component_issues/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.javascript:javascript``
```

The browser JavaScript console tells me that the URL it is trying to open is:

```
//myserver/component_issues/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.
```

... so it loses the `javascript:javascript` part.

What could be going on?

Comment: Why does your URL have two `?`'s in? Surely the list of variables should only be defined once. ID ends up being defined twice.

Also, it might filter out `javascript:` as that's used to execute it within the browser. (Bookmarklets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backbone cuts everything after (and including) "javascript:" (see http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-225).

To prevent this you should escape your parameters, i.e. have url like

```
//myserver/component_issues/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.javascript%3Ajavascript
```